# Edit excerpt with edit to wiki pending

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

I'm trying to edit a tag wiki excerpt on a beta for clarity. There is currently an edit pending on the tag wiki (not the excerpt). When I click **improve tag wiki**, I get the info page with a little link beneath the excerpt that says **edit pending** and goes to the suggested edit. There is no way to suggest an edit to the excerpt even though the edit is only on the wiki. I understand not being able to suggest an edit on an excerpt *if there is an excerpt edit pending*, but if there is no pending edit on the excerpt, the excerpt should be editable.

My feature request is to make the excerpt editable even if there is a pending edit on the wiki. Obviously, there shouldn't be this functionality when there *is* a pending edit to the excerpt.

This would also go vice versa where there is a pending edit on the excerpt, but no edit on the wiki.

This feature is more necessary on betas because it takes a *long* time to get an edit reviewed because of the few high-rep users. Also, having to wait makes one forget what they wanted to edit by the time the edit gets approved/rejected which leaves the tag unedited until the next person comes along with enough rep to edit it (again, a long time on betas for the same reason).

Comment: The problem with this is that both the excerpt and wiki are shown together when editing. Is there really a need to be able to *immediately* edit (or suggest an edit for) the excerpt or wiki while there is a pending suggested edit on the other? What's wrong with waiting?

Comment: On beta's it takes a *long* time to get an edit reviewed because of the few high-rep users. Also, having to wait makes one forget what they wanted to edit by the time the edit gets approved/rejected.